# Attach model has_and_belongs_to_many relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relationship, has-many, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models `Post` and `PostCategory` both of which have `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships.

I have created manually three `post_categories`: `news`, `don't miss` and `announcements`.

When i create a new `post` i want to be able to choose in which `categories` it `belongs to` via a `select` with `multiple="true"`.

Attention: I don't want to create a new `category` on `post` creation but to attach one or more `categories` to this `post`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do smth like:

```
form.select :category_ids, PostCategory.all.map{ |pc| [pc.name_or_smth_else, pc.id] }, {}, {:multiple => true}
```

Take a look at "4.4.1.8 collection_singular_ids" section of the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference)